# Sort ActiveRecord relation by JSON attribute from joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I sort an ActiveRecord relation in ascending order, based on the value of an attribute, where that attribute exists in a joined table, and is JSON?

First, I'm querying for members and joining the `skills` table.

```
members = Member
.select('
  member.id,
  member.skills_id,
  member.name,
  member.position,
  skills.data as data')
.join('left join skills on skills.id = member.skills_id')
```

In each member record, `skills.data` is a JSON with 2 keys, `technical` and `general`,
ie: `{'technical': 'accounting', 'general': 'planning'}`

I would like to do something like,

```
if project.status == 'complex'
  members.sort_by {|x| x['data']['technical']}
else
  members.sort_by {|x| x['data']['general']}
end
```

So I can order members based on their skill alphabetically, based on different cases. Is this possible?

Apologies if I did not explain this clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure SQL solution : if you want n result based on the order

> order by (skills.data->'technical')::text

Sort_by solution :

> members.sort_by! { |member| member.data['technical'].to_s }